# I need help solving an ODE for a range

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I've got an ODE which gives me the proper form of a solution:

```
ode = 0 == -(c + A*t)^2 + D[r[t], t]^2; 
sol = DSolve[{ode}, r[t], t]
```

The solution is:

```
{{r[t] -> (-c)*t - (A*t^2)/2 + C[1]}, {r[t] -> c*t + (A*t^2)/2 + C[1]}}
```

However, I need a solution for a definite integral rather than the indefinite form.  e.g.:

```
c*(t0 - t1)*(A*(t0 + t1))/2
```

The Mathematica help describes a form of DSolve that has a range argument, but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
sol = DSolve[{ode}, r[t], {t, t0, t1}]
```

`DSolve::alliv: The function r[t] was specified without dependence on all the independent variables. Each function must depend on all the independent variables.`

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get DSolve to give me the definite integral solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ode = 0 == -(c + A*t)^2 + D[r[t], t]^2;
sol = DSolve[{ode}, r, t]

(r[t1] - r[t0] /. sol[[1]])

(*   c t0 + (A t0^2)/2 - c t1 - (A t1^2)/2   *)
```

This is the same as

```
sol2 = Solve[ode, r'[t]]

Integrate[r'[t] /. sol2[[1]], {t, t0, t1}]

(*   c t0 + (A t0^2)/2 - c t1 - (A t1^2)/2   *)

Integrate[r'[t], {t, t0, t1}]

(*   -r[t0] + r[t1]   *)
```

Do the same for the second solution.

Comment: Thank you.  That does it.  If it's not too much to ask: how do you remove the constant of integration?  I know that r[0]=0 and r'[0]=0, but I can't seem to get the syntax right for DSolve.

Comment: you can do `Solve[(r[0] /. sol) == 0, C[1]] ` which yields C[1]->0 or directly  `sol11 = DSolve[{ode, r[0] == 0}, r, t] ` . But if you want r'[0]==0,  `(r'[0] /. sol) ` yields `{-c, c} ` that means the c has to be zero.

Comment: I thought I could use `r[0]==0` also, but I keep getting `DSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {0==-(c+A t)^2+(r^\[Prime])[t]^2,True}`  That's the exact same trouble I'm having with the syntax.

Comment: Having a diff equation of first order, you get only one constant of integration, since you integrate only once. That means, you can only impose the one condition r[0]==0 that is one order lower than the order of diff equation.